# linq to sql query with 2 dbml files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I have a object of `MyFriendFollowStatus` , for each friend I need information from 2 different databases, so I wrote something like this

```
db1Context FFdb = new db1Context();
db2Context EEdb = new db2Context();

foreach (fbFriendsFollowStatus a in fbids)
{
    long ffID = FFdb.FFUsers.Where(x => x.FacebookID == a.fbid).FirstOrDefault().FFUserID;
    a.ffID = ffID;
    int status = EEdb.StatusTable(x => x.ffID == ffid).FirstOrDefault().Status;
    a.Status = status;
}
```

this works, but it doesnt really seem right calling 2 databases - once each for each user , is there something built in LinqToSql that helps with something like this?  or sometype of join I can use using 2 different databases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can always limit your `N+1` query problem to 3 queries - one to get users, one to get user's data form first database and one for the second database. Then connect all the results in memory - this will limit the connections to databases which should improve performance of your application.

I don't know if `linq-to-sql` or `entity framework` offers building model from different databases - this would pose some performance problems probably - like in includes or something, but I may simply not be aware of such features.

Sample code to do what you're trying to achieve would look something like that:

```
var facebookIds = fbFriendsFollowStatus.Select(a => a.fbid);
var FFUserIds= FFdb.FFUsers.Where(x => facebookIds.Contains(x.FacebookID)).Select(x => new { x.FacebookID, x.FFUserId)
var statuses = EEdb.StatusTable.Where(x => FFUserIds.Contains(x.ffID)).Select(x => new { x.ffID, x.Status})
```

And then some simple code to match results in memory - but that will be simple.
Please note that this code is sample - if I've mismatched some ids or something, but idea should be clear.

Comment: so you're saying 2 foreach loops , one getting all user id's from the first db , then the next getting all status's from second db... and this will keep db connection open through the entire loop , and only need 2 connections??? I think that is what you're saying

Comment: I've addedd sample code to clear this a bit. Basically I propose 2 additional queries to get all the `FacebookId` values and `Status`es instead of `foreach` loop. In your implementation from question you have `2*N` additional queries, in my proposal you just do `2`

Comment: That's right, Linq to SQL does not allow for querying multiple databases at once, but you can create a view and then query the view.